# Are oracles too slow for DEFI arbitrage?

Tags: oracles, defi

It seems that a lot of platforms that make you money via 'arbitrage' rely on Oracles to find a profitable spread opportunity. I assume users are competing against other users (on the same platform) for the opportunity, but they will be limited by the rate that their oracles are updated.

Meanwhile, coders can create their own arbitrage solution mostly off-chain that does not require oracles to get prices, and have near real-time data. Is it fair to say that these solutions will always be the most successful arbiters?

Comment: Short answer - yes.

Comment: Long answer - also yes.

Comment: What about the really long answer?

Comment: Oh why didn't you ask? It's - hell yeah!